# Why Rails images display #<Photo:0xB4F28FA># object id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rendering, html-rendering

Here is my view:

```rb
<div>
  <ul>
  <%= @album.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <li><%= link_to(image_tag(photo.soure.url(:small)),photo.source.url(:medium)) %></li>
  <% end %>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

produces the right result except all the object ids (i.e. `#<Photo:0xXXXXXX>#`) get added right before the `</ul>` and display in the html.  I'm guessing since each time the block gets executed it returns the Photo object and that's why its rendering all the `#<Photo:0x>`s but i don't know how to STOP this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have:

```
<%= @album.photos.each do |photo| %>
```

instead of:

```
<% @album.photos.each do |photo| %>
```

Comment: too easy.  That answers a much too long question of mine, thanks!